# Dreamforce '16 - Let's Meet?

Tags: discussion, dreamforce

I've organized a meetup at Dreamforce the last few years. I won't be able to organize it this year. Anyone interested in organizing this year?

Comment: Does this mean you're not going to be at DF this year? I'd offer to organise it but I'm the worst organiser ever :)

Comment: I'm going to be there. Just trying to not spread myself thin.

Comment: @LaceySnr Didn't you organize *this site?*

Comment: I blogged and ranted a lot :) DF is always a bit hectic for me so I know what Daniel means. Maybe we do a casual lunch somewhere?

Comment: I'd be up for the casual lunch -- I'm in SF but this year, no one's comp'ing me a DF pass so if offsite - that would be great

Comment: I'm all for an informal meetup. My preference would be breakfast rather than lunch if possible.

Comment: I would be happy to meet people.  In the past, breakfast has been a popular choice because we're more likely to lose people to DF sessions later on.  I'd prefer a breakfast.

Comment: I'll be there and would very much enjoy meeting up with everyone. At the moment I don't have a clue what my schedule will look like. This will be my first DF.

Comment: I am in. I would love to meet some of the awesome US experts that saved my live so often. ;-)

Comment: I'm interested, though wouldn't be available for a Thursday morning breakfast (prior commitment).  Otherwise open and very interested in meeting you all.

Comment: It's sold out? Why that? Already that crowded? I didn't get any notification from Meta SFSE posts or comments :(

Comment: I've released my ticket.  I'm home sick with pneumonia. :-(

Answer (score 8):

I am still mainly on the Admin side but am defintely interested in meeting with fellow Developers. I look forward to more details! I tried to add this a comment but do not have the required 50 points.

Comment: Looks like you're in charge of organizing now!

Comment: I would be down for that... Im sure myself and @Nathan Pepper from the Los Angeles Developer Group could come up with something.
Can someone share with me what has been done in the past... what yall liked... and what you think could be added this year?

Comment: [Last years event details](http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/1993/102) for reference. And [2014](http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/792/102) as well.

Comment: I've booked breakfast, set up an Eventbrite, and done. Reach out to Regina Walton at Salesforce to see if they'll cover some costs. They've done it before.

Comment: Outstanding, thank you!
I will reach out after @NathanPepper and I put our heads together and get the funding and all that situated.

Comment: Good news, @MayTheSForceBeWithYou and I had a meeting with Regina from SalesForce today. We are indeed moving forward with this event and will have more details soon.
In the mean time, is there a contact yall know of that atually works at the StackExchange which we could contact for further collaboration?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: @DonaldBohrisch Try one of the [Moderators](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), they might have a contact. A couple of years ago we got stickers and shirts to give out at Dreamforce.

Comment: I think @robert-cartiano might be able to help us out with this, I'll ping him and email... thanks for taking the initiative Donald!

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Ballinger!

Comment: @LaceySnr, I appreciate that. Have you heard back from @robert-cartiano?

Comment: @MetaDaddy, wanted to involved you in this conversation as well. Would you be interested in collaborating here?

Comment: @DonaldBohrisch MetaDaddy now works for StreamSets rather than Salesforce. He (and everyone else) are of course welcome to attend from my perspective. I heard through a very indirect path that Regina from Salesforce was trying to coordinate with something else. Have you heard from her recently?

Comment: @LaceySnr I responded to your request for some swag with a few questions, can you verify that you got it?

Comment: @bluefeet I did not! No idea why, but can't find anything from your email address in my account.

Comment: Hmmm @LaceySnr not from team@?

Comment: @bluefeet Nope! Not that I can find :(

Comment: @LaceySnr Shoot me an email with with your request, then.  Include what you think you'll need (for how many people), the address it needs to be sent to, and when you need it by.

Comment: @DanielBallinger Yes, in order to limit cost to attendees and get the most out of the event we worked with Regina@SalesForce. The event is setup and ready for people to RSVP.
Click this link: http://bit.ly/DF16devbfast
Enter this password: DF16devs
What do you think is the best way to get the event out there to those here in our community which might want to go?

Comment: @bluefeet & LaceySnr The event has been setup as per the above comment. Can you please include me on the emails you were mentioning @ SalesForceHire@gmail.com .
Do you have any ideas on how to get this info to the rest of our community on here?
Click this link: http://bit.ly/DF16devbfast
Enter this password: DF16devs

Comment: @DonaldBohrisch How widely are we allowed to circulate this? Is it open to all? If so, I'll start tweeting it etc... Maybe a new Meta Post here with the required details.

Comment: Yeah a new post would be a good start. I signed up yesterday.

Comment: @bluefeet RE swag: waiting on Salesforce to give the OK on having branded goodies available at this event. Turns out they can get a bit funny about it :/

Comment: @LaceySnr Branded goodies meaning Salesforce branded or other branded?  From us it would be Stack Exchange branded.

Comment: As in the event is going to be at a Salesforce office and apparently there might be rules about having branded goods from other companies there. Huge community support there :/

Comment: @LaceySnr - I dont believe its an issue with the Swag being there at the breakfast... just with having it shipped there and storing it. When Nathan Pepper(MayTheSForceBeWithYou - below) and I talked with Regina she sounded like she wanted some Stack Exchange swag to distribute as the whole purpose was to bring both Dev communities closer.
As I mentioned in the other conversation though... I have an address we can ship the swag to and I can transport it as needed.

Comment: @LaceySnr We're coming up to the end of a timeframe to be able to get anything sent out. I never received an email with details on where to send swag or how much you'd need.  Do you have any of this info?

Comment: @bluefeet, I have an address in the bay area which stuff can be mailed to if need be. Please email me if you need it. SalesForceHire@gmail.com

Comment: @DonaldBohrisch We've got it already set up and taken care of.

Answer (score 7):

Here it is!

http://bit.ly/DF16devbfast
Password: DF16devs

Comment: Just to be clear: this is not a dedicated salesforce.stackexchange meeting but we're joining/crashing/taking over/..  the Salesforce organized Dev Community Breakfast right ? (definitely helps me not having to be at two places at the same time)

Comment: I just found out and it's sold out!? :)

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke That is correct, it's a Dev Group Leader / MVP / everyone else who can fit event.  I'm looking forward to this being more of a developer community / forum grassroots event next year to encourage and promote participation in Salesforce Developer Forums and Salesforce StackExchange.

Comment: Ditto, just found out and now it's sold out!  Really sad.  Is there no way for me now to join any sort of meetup with the marvelous people of SFSE?  :-(

Comment: I've released my ticket.  I'm home sick with pneumonia. :-(

Comment: It was awesome! So great to see you all... until November, '17!

Comment: Thanks for extending the invite to the SFSE community at the DF16 Dev Community Breakfast. It was great to finally put a face to the avatars of @AdrianLarson and Daniel Ballinger. Looking forward to the next one. Perhaps it's time we started an SFSE conference!

Answer (score 1):

FYI, 2016 session video seems to be going up in the "Agenda Builder" for attendees at https://success.salesforce.com/MyAgenda?eventId=a1Q3000000qQOd9EAG.

If you didn't go, have a friend who attended click on a particular session, inspect the page source for "vidyard_embed_code_", and get you the text that follows within the `id="..."` tag.

Then paste that ID after http://play.vidyard.com/ - that's the public link to the video.

In other words, "vidyard_embed_code_XYZZY" becomes http://play.vidyard.com/XYZZY

(Same process works for 2015 - "agenda builder" link is at https://success.salesforce.com/Ev_MyAgenda?eventId=a1Q30000000DHQlEAO and requires a login, but the Vidyard-hosted content doesn't, once you know where it is.)

Comment: If you're a clever screen-scraper, go to Agenda Builder, click on a day, comb the source for elements like `<li data-id="a2q2B000035up7qEIW" class="itemlist-card session-item">`, & for each, grab the "data-id" value and pull it up like `https://success.salesforce.com/MyAgenda?eventId=a1Q3000000qQOd9EAG#/session/a2q2B000035up7qEIW`. Then grab the "vidyard" code and perhaps the title of the session from the source code.  Voila, list of links to videos of sessions you'd been interested in for quick future reference. [No time to work through this myself, unfortunately, but dream of it...]

Answer (score 0):

It was great seeing yall @DF16! I hope everyone who attended it enjoyed it. If there are any suggestions/comments please feel free to be candid so that we can provide a better experience next year. Both likes and dislikes are welcome.