# Dreamforce 2017 Salesforce StackExchange Meetup?

Tags: discussion, dreamforce

Are we going to have a SFSE meetup at Dreamforce 2017? This attached pic is from the SFSE meetup at Dreamforce 2015 and remains one of my all time favorite DF memories.

[image]

Hoping for an encore this year!

Comment: I hope to see an another pic like this after dreamforce !

Comment: Last year the event got rolled up with the Salesforce Developer Event breakfast thing. Can't seem to find a reference to in on here in meta anymore.

Comment: I enjoy these meetups. I missed DF last year so I didn't get to experience the Dev Event.

Comment: I intend to be at DF this year, so if you do get something going, make sure I'm invited. I'd love to meet y'all!

Comment: I'm interested.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Daniel Hoechst managed it at DF15, not sure who can coordinate this year. Perhaps, the SFSE moderators can lead/ guide on this?

Comment: For those interested, [have a link to last year's meetup discussion](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2262/dreamforce-16-lets-meet). Most of the planning/information was hashed out in the comments.

Comment: I'll try reaching out to the Salesforce Dev Community people to see if there is any support this year or if they are planning a general developer event.

Comment: Sad that I'll be missing out this year... Have fun!

Comment: I'll be Dreamforcing this year! :)

Comment: Let's do this thing!

Comment: I haven't been since 2014, but my memories are "pleasant" enough to investigate 3 years later! Let's do this.

Answer (score 6):

Feedback so far about a combined developer community meetup.

> We've requested space for these types of community meetups, but as you know, space is hard to come by. We don't have any leads on space right now, but we have a few asks out there and will let you know if anything pops up.

Comment: Great stuff! Hoping this works out well!

Comment: Any updates? Anybody want to meet up for breakfast somewhere if it doesn't work out?

Comment: I've got a lead on some private event space across the street from Moscone West, if someone wants to contact me.

Comment: Ping @adrian...

Comment: I'm happy to try to organize. I will email you shortly. What time and day? @JDB

Comment: Let me know what you sort out. No time to help organise, but happy to help promote

Comment: @adrian looking at Thursday morning. Still waiting on exact time.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - I think I've got everything sorted out. Will be posting an answer with invites momentarily.

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** There's still room. If you didn't get a chance to fill out the registration form, please go ahead and do that soon so that I'll know how many to expect.

---

[Skuid](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wyDjEAI) is very pleased to be able to host an unofficial Salesforce Stack Exchange meetup at the Skuid Lagoon in the Elan (right across the street from Moscone West) during the 2017 Dreamforce event. We'll have some snacks and light breakfast options.

[image]

**Location:**
Skuid Lagoon at Elan Event Venue
[839 Howard St](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Elan+Event+Venue/@37.7823734,-122.4034857,15z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0xdb63b7783b7ac71e!8m2!3d37.7823734!4d-122.4034857)

**Time:**
Thursday, November 9th
9:00-10:00 am

(Feel free to stay afterward for a Skuid presentation)

Space is limited, so be sure to reserve a spot using this form!
https://goo.gl/forms/MjoUW6B1SobjhOMq1

*(I'm the bald guy with the beard in the back of that 2015 photo. )*

Comment: This sounds like a go! Right now that time works for me though everything is super fluid with clients this week.

Comment: I tried to do something a bit earlier, but this was the best time for the event space. Apologies if it doesn't work with everyone's scheduled... it was obviously very last-minute. :)

Comment: Didn't read this on time and missed it among all the madness that typically goes on with the 4 packed days at DF. Please do share some pictures from the meetup. Thanks!

Comment: Gah! So sad I missed this. Not sure when "next time" will be as my company will be rotating between staff who get to come each year. It was a blast though!