# Salesforce Stackexchange members @ dreamforce mvp event

Tags: discussion, dreamforce

This was my first Dreamforce and I was lucky enough to meet soooo many awesome people from the community and some of the bright minds from the stack exchange contributors..

here's some pics taken during the mvp event this dreamforce where we managed to pull some of our contributors ( & some photo bombs :-) ) for a quick snap..

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting these Vamsi! It was great meeting you!

Comment: Did anyone make it to the [last minute unofficial Dreamforce meetup](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2654/102)?  I couldn't due to conflicts, but would be interested in seeing any pictures from that as well.

Comment: There were just three of us so no pictures. @DanielBallinger